# What does "Die Weichen waren gestellt" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I am reading Peter Zolling´s "Deutsche Geschichte von 1871 bis zur Gegenwart". Can someone please help me understand the sentence:

> Die Weichen waren gestellt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- literally: the (railroad) switches have been set
- meaning: the
  actions/decisions concerning the future were taken; the future is
  predetermined because of something